# Limit of piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces. If I have two functions $a:X\supseteq A  \rightarrow Y$ and $b:X\supseteq B \rightarrow Y$ and define a third piecewise function $f: X \supseteq (A \cup B)\rightarrow Y$ with $$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            a(x) & \quad x \in A \\
            b(x) & \quad x \in B
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$, is it correct that if $x_0$ is a limit point of both $A$ and $B$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}a(x)=L=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}b(x)$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=L$?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ disjoint, or do we have that $a(x)=b(x)$ for $x\in A\cap B$?

Comment: @ThePhenotype I thought of $A$ and $B$ being disjoint, does this have impact on the correctness of the statement?

Comment: What are $A$,$B$,$X$ and $Y$ exactly? Banach spaces?

Comment: @JakobElias I wanted to know whether that holds in general metric spaces (so $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ are some metric space), although I suspect the statement is wrong and I missed something somewhere. I'm not sure whether completeness changes something.

Comment: Ok, I understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then, yes, it is correct. Let $\varepsilon>0$. You know that there is a neighborhood $N_A$ of $x_0$ such that$$\tag{1}(\forall x\in A\cap N_A):d_Y\bigl(a(x),L\bigr)<\varepsilon$$and that there is a neighborhood $N_B$ of $x_0$ such that$$\tag{2}(\forall x\in B\cap N_B):d_Y\bigl(b(x),L\bigr)<\varepsilon.$$Let $N=N_A\cap N_B$. Then $N$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ and it is a consequence of $(1)$ and of $(2)$ that$$\bigl(\forall x\in(A\cup B)\cap N\bigr):d_Y\bigl(f(x),L\bigr)<\varepsilon.$$Since that happens for each $\varepsilon>0$, $\lim_{x\to x_o}f(x)=L$